# How to get the last updated value of a value in sql

Tags: teradata

[sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pysI8.png) I have 2 columns old_store_id, changed_new_store_id and there are cases when changed_new_store_id value will also get updated to new value. how can i traverse through DB(teradata) to get the last value (changed_new_store_id ) of the respective old_store_id

let say in 1 st row 
old_store_id = A ;
changed_new_store_id = B

and  5 th row contains

old_store_id = B ;
changed_new_store_id = C

and some other nth row C is changed to X etc

how to get  final value of A which is X ?

I can try using multiple self joins

using Stored procedure but it will not be an efficient way (for many reasons)
Is there any way to find ?
Please anyone suggest me

Comment: Do you have a date or timestamp column on which you can sort, where you can just pick the last `changed_new_store_id`? If not a Recursive CTE is probably your best bet. If you can share some sample data and your desired results we can probably help you out a bit more.

Comment: i dont have time stamp column ,I have added an image of sample data, hope it give a bit more clarity, Final in the image is the final value of respective old value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes no "loops", and uses "bottom-up" recursion. Something very similar could be done "top-down", limiting the seed query to rows where the "old" value doesn't appear anywhere as a "new" value.

```
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE #Example (
    Old_Store_ID VARCHAR(8),
    New_Store_ID VARCHAR(8)
)
PRIMARY INDEX(Old_Store_ID)
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

INSERT INTO #Example VALUES ('A', 'B');
INSERT INTO #Example VALUES ('D', 'c');
INSERT INTO #Example VALUES ('B', 'F');
INSERT INTO #Example VALUES ('c', 'FF');
INSERT INTO #Example VALUES ('FF', 'GG');
INSERT INTO #Example VALUES ('F', 'X');

WITH RECURSIVE #Traverse(Old_Store_ID,New_Store_ID,Final_ID)
AS
(
--Seed Query - start with only the rows having no further changes
SELECT      Old_Store_ID 
            ,New_Store_ID 
            ,New_Store_ID as Final_ID

  FROM      #Example as This
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1 FROM #Example AS Other WHERE This.New_Store_ID = Other.Old_Store_ID
      )

UNION ALL

--Recursive Join
SELECT      NewRow.Old_Store_ID  
            ,NewRow.New_Store_ID
            ,OldRow.Final_ID

  FROM      #Example AS NewRow 
            INNER JOIN #Traverse AS OldRow
            ON NewRow.New_Store_ID = OldRow.Old_Store_ID 
)
SELECT *
  FROM      #Traverse
  ;
```

Comment: Thank you for this simpler answer :)

Comment: Hi @Fred, can you explain me the use of recursive join in the query, is it executing n times it self or will it be executing with the help of seed query every time.

Comment: The seed query is executed once, then the other query (after the UNION ALL) is executed repeatedly. On each iteration, the recursive reference (to #Traverse, in this case) uses the output of the prior query. Recursion stops when an iteration results in no rows.

Comment: Thanks a lot fred for giving detailed exp

Answer (score 0):

A recursive answer:

```
CREATE VOLATILE TABLE #SearchList (
    SearchID       CHAR(2),
    ParentSearchID CHAR(2)
)
PRIMARY INDEX(SearchID)
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

INSERT INTO #SearchList VALUES ('A', 'B');
INSERT INTO #SearchList VALUES ('D', 'c');
INSERT INTO #SearchList VALUES ('B', 'F');
INSERT INTO #SearchList VALUES ('c', 'FF');
INSERT INTO #SearchList VALUES ('FF', 'GG');
INSERT INTO #SearchList VALUES ('F', 'X');

CREATE VOLATILE TABLE #IntermediateResults( 

    SearchID       CHAR(2),
    ParentSearchID CHAR(2),
    SearchLevel    INTEGER
)
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

INSERT INTO #IntermediateResults
WITH RECURSIVE RecursiveParent(SearchID,ParentSearchID,SearchLevel)
AS
(
--Seed Query
SELECT      SearchID 
            ,ParentSearchID 
            ,1

  FROM      #SearchList

UNION ALL

--Recursive Join
SELECT      a.SearchID  
            ,b.ParentSearchID
            ,SearchLevel+1

  FROM      #SearchList a 

            INNER JOIN RecursiveParent b
            ON a.ParentSearchID = b.SearchID 
)
SELECT      SearchID
            ,ParentSearchID
            ,MAX(SearchLevel)

  FROM      RecursiveParent

GROUP BY    SearchID
            ,ParentSearchID
;

SELECT      RESULTS.*

  FROM      #IntermediateResults RESULTS

            INNER JOIN (SELECT      RESULTS_MAX.SearchID
                                    ,MAX(RESULTS_MAX.SearchLevel) MaxSearchLevel

                          FROM      #IntermediateResults RESULTS_MAX

                        GROUP BY    RESULTS_MAX.SearchID
                       ) GROUPED_RESULTS
            ON RESULTS.SearchID = GROUPED_RESULTS.SearchID
            AND RESULTS.SearchLevel = GROUPED_RESULTS.MaxSearchLevel

ORDER BY     RESULTS.SearchID    ASC
            ,RESULTS.SearchLevel ASC
;
```

Output:

```
SearchID  ParentSearchID  SearchLevel
--------  --------------  -----------
A         X               3
B         X               2
c         GG              2
D         GG              3
F         X               1
FF        GG              1
```